# Push notifications only work every now and then

Tags: ipod-touch, notifications

My iPods push notifications only work every now and then and I'm always on the same router. All my notification settings are turned on but like I said they only work occasionally. Does anyone know how to fix this so they work everyday all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Is your iDevice jailbroken?
If it is you could potentially use Push Doctor to fix the push problems you're having.

Comment: No my iPod is not jail broken but thank you

Answer (score 1):

Which notifications are you not getting all the time. I know that there are some applications that aren't written properly or are written in a way that you wouldn't expect that cause you not to get a notification when you think you will. For instance, Facebook. If you're on facebook on your computer and you get a notification it doesn't get pushed to your phone right away, it'll wait a bit to see if you're actually going to check it another way first before sending it to the phone.

Comment: I get them from any of my apps like facebook or txtplus for like five min. And then for like two weeks my push notifications won't work. Then randomly it will again. They only work for like five - ten min and then they always stop.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your DNS to `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It's not okay to be rude like this. The premise of participating in this site is helping people, and if you want to participate you need to be able to do that graciously. Secondly, please add some more detail to this answer. How do you change your DNS server and what will that accomplish? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.